# Left Join com vários campos da mesma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi

Para montar um contrato de locação, tenho duas tabelas.

A primeira que é a do contrato, possui alguns campos de relacionamento como `id_locador`, `id_locatario`, `id_fiador1`, `id_fiador2`, dentre outros. Esses campos são relacionados a uma tabela de pessoas: `id`, `nome`, `endereco`, etc.

Então todas as pessoas envolvidas no contrato vêm da mesma tabela "pessoas".

***Como fazer esse relacionamento?***

Answer (score 5):

O que você precisa é algo do tipo, pra cada relação de `contrato` com sua tabela `pessoa`, você adiciona um `left join`

```
select C.ID_CONTRATO, PT.NOME AS TITULAR, PR.NOME AS RESPONSAVEL, PN.NOME AS NOTA
from 
    CONTRATO C 
        LEFT JOIN PESSOA PT ON C.ID_PESSOA = PT.ID_PESSOA
        LEFT JOIN PESSOA PR ON C.ID_PESSOA_RESPONSAVEL = PR.ID_PESSOA
        LEFT JOIN PESSOA PN ON C.ID_PESSOA_NOTA = PN.ID_PESSOA
```

Answer (score -1):

Quando você faz um left join ele automaticamente tará os resultados daquela junção tendo linhas ou não, pois o left join ele funciona como uma junção das tabelas mas atendendo a sua condição como se fosse um or, se você quer voltar dados mais concisos use inner join